# django-leaflet + django-geojson: I can't place a marker in Admin (TypeError: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.finish is undefined)

Tags: python, django, leaflet

This might be trivial but I can't find the mistake. I'm just getting the initial setup done following the documentation on GitHub. I've started a new app. Installed [django-leaflet](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet) and [django-geojson](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson), created a minimal models.py as well as admin.py.

When I try to place a marker on the map via the admin. Nothing happens, and the icons on the left for drawing markers and polygons is missing.

I must be missing a dependencies, forgot something trivial. But I've been over and over the docs, and I must have stared myself blind.

I haven't created a view or template. Only the model and admin. And migrated the database.

---

Here is the console log from Chrome and Firefox.

**`Chrome`**

```
spritesheet.svg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
leaflet.draw.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at e.getActions (leaflet.draw.js:9)
    at e._createActions (leaflet.draw.js:9)
    at e._showActionsToolbar (leaflet.draw.js:9)
    at e._handlerActivated (leaflet.draw.js:9)
    at e.fireEvent (leaflet.js:6)
    at enable (leaflet.draw.js:8)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.s [as _leaflet_click33] (leaflet.js:8)
```

**`Firefox`**

```
10:34:46.995 TypeError: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.finish is undefined 1 leaflet.draw.js:9:15973

    L.DrawToolbar<.getActions        http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/leaflet/draw/leaflet.draw.js:9:15973
    L.Toolbar<._createActions        http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/leaflet/draw/leaflet.draw.js:9:12001
    L.Toolbar<._showActionsToolbar   http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/leaflet/draw/leaflet.draw.js:9:12614
    L.Toolbar<._handlerActivated     http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/leaflet/draw/leaflet.draw.js:9:11700
    o.Evented<.fire                  http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/leaflet/leaflet.js:5:4955
    L.Draw.Feature<.enable           http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/leaflet/draw/leaflet.draw.js:8:1810
    o.DomEvent._on/h                 http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/leaflet/leaflet.js:6:11671
```

---

**`installed packages`**

```
appdirs==1.4.0
Django==1.10.5
django-geojson==2.9.1
django-leaflet==0.20.0
jsonfield==1.0.3
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
Pillow==4.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
pyparsing==2.1.10
six==1.10.0
```

---

**`geodjango/settings.py`**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'leaflet',
    'djgeojson',
    'djangomap',
]
```

---

**`djangomap/models.py`**

```
from django.db import models
from djgeojson.fields import PointField

class MapMarker(models.Model):
    geom = PointField()
```

**`djangomap/admin.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin

from djangomap.models import MapMarker

admin.site.register(MapMarker, LeafletGeoAdmin)
```

Comment: i have the exact same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-leaflet 0.20.0 required leaflet.draw 0.4 but provide 0.3.
Pull request to fix this is here https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet/pull/179 but it still not merged and merged on Feb 28, 2017.

Prior to the merge, the workaround was: 

`pip uninstall django-leaflet
pip install django-leaflet-cadasta`